# Trouble baking normal map from high to low poly model to smooth out edges

Tags: uv, texture-baking, normal-map

I want to bake the high poly details to a normal map (to smooth out/round the edges while keeping low poly count), but get unexpected results. (Strange artifacts and edges not smoothed/rounded out) I've tried many different bake settings and checked UV's/Normals but no success.

blend file:[image]

Edges not rounded out and weird artifacts (smooth high poly on left):
[image: 1]

[image]

Normal map:
[image]

Topology:
[image]

Bake settings:
[image]

High and low poly models:
[image]

Comment: Multiple problems: 1) Make sure HP has the shape you want, and remove the mat from it; 2) use sufficient ray extrusion for LP to completely enclose HP, or use a cage; 3) improve LP topo and get rid of sharp edges, custom normals, and autosmooth on LP.